# Why is it returning None instead of True or False?

Tags: python-3.x, function, decorator

this code is for checking if a word is a palindrome or not, and the decorator check if the word is a string

```
def check(func):
    def string(w):
        if w != str(w):
            print('no')
        else:
            print('yes')
        func(w)
    return string



@check
def palindrome(w):
    print(w)
    inverse = ''
    inverse = w[::-1]
    if inverse == w:
        print('1')
        return True
    else:
        print('2')
        return False


print(palindrome("test"))
```

After running it:

```
yes
test
2
None
```

At this point, everything should be ok, but I don't know why it is returning `None` instead of True or False.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you provide your code for the `check` decorator? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your check decorator ignores return value from decorated function. You need explicit return in wrapper function:

```
def check(func):
    def string(w):
        if w != str(w):
            print('no')
        else:
            print('yes')
        return func(w)
    return string
```